Console placed in strategy callback is not showing up
I'm following the official documentation of passport for LinkedIn Authentication  but the issue I faced was that any console placed in LinkedIn Strategy Callback was not showing and I was unable to find the values of accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done in this callback.
However I tried another solution. I manually added API requests in callback controller (not strategy callback) from where I extracted user info and then used that for my database operations.
Now, what I'm confused about whether is this the standard practice or these API calls are supposed to get triggered automatically? I wasn't able to see the consoles placed in callback function of LinkedIn strategy.
passport.use(
  new LinkedInStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'https://analyser-node.octalooptechnologies.com/auth/linkedin/callback',
      scope: [ 'email', 'openid', 'profile'],
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
        console.log('Profile Object:', profile);
        let user = await User.findOne({ linkedinId: profile.id });

        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }

        user = await User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value });
        if (user) {
          if (!user.linkedinId) {
            user.linkedinId = profile.id;
            user.verify = true;
            await user.save();
          }
          console.log('user in strategy:', user);
          
          return done(null, user);
        }

        const newUser = new User({
          linkedinId: profile.id,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          verify: true,
        });
        await newUser.save();
        done(null, newUser);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in strategy:', error);
        done(error, null);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('user in passport serializer:', user);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, null);
  }
});

exports.linkedinAuth = passport.authenticate('linkedin', { state: true, scope: [ 'email', 'openid', 'profile']});

exports.linkedinAuthCallback = async(req, res) => {
  try {
   //step 1 : here we get this code from passport linkedin strategy.
    const code = req.query.code;
    // console.log("code:", code);
  
    const redirect_uri = "https://analyser-node.octalooptechnologies.com/auth/linkedin/callback";
    const client_id = process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID
    const client_secret = process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET

    var access_token;
    //step 2 : access token retrieval
    const access_token_url = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}`;
    const res_token = await axios.post(access_token_url)
    .then((res) => {
    access_token = res.data.access_token;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    });
    console.log("access_token:", access_token);

    const user_info_url = `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo`;
  if (access_token) {
   const res_user_info = await axios
    .get(user_info_url, {
     headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
     },
    })
    .then((response) => {
     user_info = response.data;
     console.log('user_info:', user_info);

      const dbOperations = async () => {
        try {
          let userLinkedinId = await User.findOne({ linkedinId: user_info.sub });
          let userEmail = await User.findOne({ email: user_info.email });
          const userId = userEmail?._id
          if (userLinkedinId && userEmail) {
            // 1) if linkedinId exists in database
            // console.log('userEmail:', userEmail);
            // console.log('userLinkedinId:', userLinkedinId);
            try {
              const token = jwt.sign({ userId: userId, email: user_info.email }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
              console.log('token_1:', token);
              
              const redirectUrl = `https://cv-analyzer-git-staging-octalooptechnologies-projects.vercel.app/recommendation?token=${token}&userId=${userId}`;
              res.redirect(redirectUrl);
            } catch (jwtError) {
              console.error('JWT generation error:', jwtError);
              res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error during JWT generation' });
            }
          } else if (userEmail && !userLinkedinId) {
              // 2) if only email exists in database
              // console.log('userEmail:', userEmail);
              // console.log('userLinkedinId:', userLinkedinId);

              const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {email: user_info.email },  // Find by user ID
                { $set: { linkedinId: user_info.sub } },  // Add the new attribute
                { new: true }  // Optionally return the updated document
              );
              console.log('Updated user:', updatedUser);
            try {
              const token = jwt.sign({ userId: userId, email: user_info.email }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
              console.log('token_2:', token);
              
              const redirectUrl = `https://cv-analyzer-git-staging-octalooptechnologies-projects.vercel.app/recommendation?token=${token}&userId=${userId}`;
              res.redirect(redirectUrl);
            } catch (jwtError) {
              console.error('JWT generation error:', jwtError);
              res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error during JWT generation' });
            }
          } else if (!userEmail && !userLinkedinId) {
            // 3) if neither email nor linkedinId exists in database
            // console.log('userEmail:', userEmail);
            // console.log('userLinkedinId:', userLinkedinId);
            // console.log('newUser is about to be generated');
                    
            const newUser = new User({
              linkedinId: user_info.sub,
              email: user_info.email,
              verify: true,
              profileImage: user_info.picture
            });
            console.log('newUser:', newUser);

            const savedNewUser = await newUser.save();
            console.log('savedNewUser:', savedNewUser);
            const userId = savedNewUser._id
            
            try {
              const token = jwt.sign({ userId: userId, email: user_info.email }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
              console.log('token_3:', token);
              
              const redirectUrl = `https://cv-analyzer-git-staging-octalooptechnologies-projects.vercel.app/recommendation?token=${token}&userId=${userId}`;
              res.redirect(redirectUrl);
            } catch (jwtError) {
              console.error('JWT generation error:', jwtError);
              res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error during JWT generation' });
            }
          }

          
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error:', error);
        }
      }
      dbOperations()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
     console.log("ERROR: ", err);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("access_token not found");
  }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('internal error:', error);
    
    res.status(500).json({
     message: "Internal Server Error",
     error,
    })}
}


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
